# How to update separate counters dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an application which currently has 2 people ("Mom" and "Dad"). Each person should have their own counter which increments independently.

**My XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.jarrall.apps.annoyed.MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mom"
        android:id="@+id/textViewMom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bs"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewMom"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Dad"
        android:id="@+id/textViewDad"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bs"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewDad"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textViewDad"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/buttonsDad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewDad"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/total_text_view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="2"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**My Java code:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int counter = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


/**
 * This method is called when the plus button is clicked.
 */
public void increment(View view) {
    counter = counter + 1;
    display(counter);
   /*  displayPrice(counter * 5); */
}

/**
 * This method is called when the minus button is clicked.
 */
public void decrement(View view) {
    counter = counter - 1;
    display(counter);
}

/**
 * This method displays the given counter value on the screen.
 */
private void display(int number) {
    TextView counterTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total_text_view);
    counterTextView.setText("" + number);
}
}
```

How would I edit my code such that when a button is pressed for either mom or dad and the `display()` method is called that it increments/decreases the corresponding textView (Either `@+id/total_text_view` or `@+id/total_text_view2`).

Currently both sets of buttons effect only the first `textView` (`@+id/total_text_view`) under mom

Comment: post your question like this: http://sscce.org/. there is too much uneccessary code...

Answer (score 0):

Make a few functions;

`incrementMom()`, `decrementMom()`, `incrementDad()` and `decrementDad()`

then just instead of using `android:onClick="decrement"` use either `android:onClick="decrementMom"` or `android:onClick="decrementDad"`

Comment: I think you can make variable called 'type'  , according to this variable value do something , ex if(type=="DAD") do something

Comment: Feel free to accept it if it gets the job done. And no, you cannot via XML @MinaFawzy